# How to have a multiple upload in PHP?

Tags: php, upload, gallery

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $album_id = $_POST['album'];
   $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $random_name = rand();
   if(empty($name) or empty($file)) {
     echo "Please Fill all the Fields ! <br /><br />";
   } else {             
     move_uploaded_file$file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos VALUE('', '$name', '$album_id', '$random_name.jpg')");             
     echo "Photo Uploaded !! <br /><br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL have a look in this

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960239/multiple-image-upload/35960865#35960865

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960239/multiple-image-upload/35960865#35960865

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed to do it hope this helps

```
    <?
    function openDB()
     {
                global $conn, $username,$host,$password,$db;
                    $host = "localhost";
                    $username ="username";
                    $password= "password";
                    $db = "databasename";
                        $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
                        mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }  
    function closeDB()
    {
        global $conn;
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
    ?>

    <form action="<? echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
            <td><input type="file" accept="image/*" name="product_image" size="60">        
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Product File1:</b></td>
            <td><input type="file" accept="*/*" name="product_support_file" size="60">        
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Product File2:</b></td>
            <td><input type="file" accept="*/*" name="product_support_file2" size="60">        
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_price" size="60" required></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="right"><input type="submit" name="insert_product" value="Insert Product Now"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?
    openDB();
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
        $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
        $product_type = $_POST['product_type'];
        $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
        $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
        $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
        $product_link = $_POST['product_link'];

        //getting the image from the feild

        $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp'];   
        $product_support_file = $_FILES['product_support_file']['name'];
        $product_support_file_tmp = $_FILES['product_support_file']['tmp'];
        $product_support_file2 = $_FILES['product_support_file2']['name'];
        $product_support_file2_tmp = $_FILES['product_support_file2']['tmp'];

    if(isset($_POST['insert_product']))
    {
        //gets the Text Feild Data
         $insert_product = "insert into products(product_id,product_cat, product_type, product_title, 
                product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_support_file, product_support_file2, product_keywords,product_link)                  
                values('','$product_cat','$product_type','$product_title',
                '$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_support_file','$product_support_file2','$product_keywords','$product_link')";   


            if(mysql_query($insert_product))
            {
                //echo "
                //Please enter the file path you wish to add your image to:
                //<br><input type='text' name='' value=''></input>";
                $file_directory ="../yourdirectory";    

                foreach($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array)
                {               
                    if(is_uploaded_file($file_array["tmp_name"]))
                    {
                        move_uploaded_file($file_array["tmp_name"],"$file_directory/"
                        .$file_array["name"]) or die ("Could not copy");
                    }

                }
                echo"<script language='Javascript'>window.open('ConformationUpload.php');</script>";

            }
            else{
                echo"Product adding has been unsuccessfull<b>",mysql_error(),"</b>";
            }
    closeDB();
    }
?>
```